# Select implementation class in deep hierarchies

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

I am creating a Python module with the requirement that the end-user of this module can select a specific implementation of a class that will be used by various other classes throughout the module (preferably with a default implementation).

One constraint is that this class is embedded in deep hierarchies. Here is a minimal example illustrating the problem:

```py
class X():
    pass

class Y():
    pass

Z = X # or Z = Y

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.zoo = Z()

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.zoo = Z()

class C(B):
    pass
```

For the purpose of this example, I used the global variable `Z` to define what class will be selected. This is indeed not ideal and requires the user to *monkey patch*/change the global variable after import. This also prevent mixing different implementations in the same project.

```py
from my_module import A, B, C, Y, Z

Z=Y

class U():
    def __init__():
        self.foo = C()
```

What would be your preferred approach to solve this issue? I'd like to avoid passing the class as a constructor parameter since choosing e.g. `X` or `Y` should be linked to the class and not the instance. Since Python doesn't support parametrized import, I thought about decorators and metaclasses but couldn't come up with a clean design.

Comment: Any implementation will require to choose class you want to work with. Or you want to do a config?

Comment: This pattern seems prone to subtle errors that will occur when some code executes when the module is loaded, with the default `Z` value, whereas other code will execute with the modified `Z` value.

Comment: you can factory pattern to create and use class you need at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your instances of `C` are either using `X` or `Y`, but which it is, is decided by the user of class `C` who also should be allowed to mix the usage of both.  In such a case the instances should receive the decision at creation time of the instances, that means as an argument to the constructor:

```
class X():
    pass

class Y():
    pass

class A():
    def __init__(self, x_or_y):
        # you will find a more fitting name in your
        # concrete case than x_or_y ;-)
        self.x_or_y = x_or_y
        self.zoo = x_or_y()

class B():
    def __init__(self, x_or_y):
        self.x_or_y = x_or_y
        self.zoo = x_or_y()

class C(B):
    pass
```

Creation of an instance is then done like this:

```
from my_module import A, B, C, Y

class U():
    def __init__():
        self.foo = C(Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to do something like what [wxPython does for their version management](https://wiki.wxpython.org/MultiVersionInstalls).  This would involve splitting your code into three parts: a library of classes, the actual business logic, and a selector module.

library.py

```
from abc import ABC

class Base(ABC):
    ...

class Impl1(Base):
    ...

class Impl2(Base):
    ...
```

selector.py

```
from typing import Type
import library 

impl= library.Impl1

def set_impl(cls: Type[library.Base]):
    global impl
    impl = cls
```

core.py

```
import library
import selector 

impl = selector.impl

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.zoo = impl()
```

Then in the code that uses your package, you just have to be sure to call `set_impl` before importing `core.py`:

```
import library
import selector
selector.set_impl(library.Impl2)

import core
print(core.impl)  # <class 'library.Impl2'>
```

This works because the module object that gets created for the `selector` module is only created once, and every other module shares it.  So when the main module modifies `selector`, those changes are visible to `core`